# In hql, how to compare 'date in db' with 'java date'

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
FROM InitialMedicalCheckUpEntity where month(date)= month(:date)";
query.setParameter("date",date);
```

I want to compare dates using hibernate query language like the above code. Please tell me how i could do that

Comment: your code should just work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Hibernate docs http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Escpecially section 14.10 on expressions allowed in the `WHERE` clause, including:

> second(...), minute(...), hour(...), day(...), month(...), and year(...)